# ubuntu to ubuntu backup in internal network

Tags: ubuntu, backup

hey, i got my development "home" server witch is ubuntu 10, i brought today a computer in order to make a backup to this computer (the development server does also to him self backups every day but im paranoaid so i want to have two backups just in case on diffrent computers)

what is the best way to backup the system core of the development server (like norton ghost) & do a full & incrmnt backup of him to the new computer that ive brought? rsync? rdiff? scp? clonezilla?

Answer (score 0):

You can never be too paranoid about backups, they are life-safers ;-).

I have always used to clonezilla for that and in my experience it works like a charm. Never had any problems with it. The only downside is not having incremental backups, so that you waste some storage.

Another solution wich you migh want to consider is mondo: http://www.mondorescue.org/
From their references it seems quite mature and reliable. However it is definitly way more complex than clonezilla, if you can spare the downtime during the backup (I can, which is why I never used it^^).